Анализ покрытия кода тестами в C++ builder 11.2
Для сертификации программы нужен анализ покрытия кода тестами. Ни разу с этим не сталкивался. Информации о том, как это сделать в C++ Builder нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать, как разобраться? Можно ссылки на статьи и пр.
